# Is possible to mysql change some engine tables automatically?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 WordPress blog hosted on cPanel using MySQL. All 3 of them were working fine until yesterday. Now, the support says that “some tables changed from 'MyISAM' to InnoDB”.

In the logs I get:

```
[mydb.wp_usermeta] Error: Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'
[mydb.wp_usermeta] error: Corrupt
```

And the same for other tables.

I don't know why those tables changed the engine. Is it possible for MySQL to have changed it automatically for some reason?

Comment: No. Check MySQL logs for ALTER TABLE and define its source.

Comment: @gog, Never automatically change any of MySQL storage engine to other one.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE `%engine%`;
```

Of interest are `default_storage_engine`, which was MyISAM in older versions, but is now `InnoDB`.  This comes into play when you do `CREATE TABLE` without including `ENGINE=...`.

Also of interest is `enforce_storage_engine`.  This strengthens the previous setting by not letting you create a table of Engine other than the default.

When changing (`ALTER TABLE .. ENGINE=..`) a table from one engine to another, there are some number of potential pitfalls.  I cover MyISAM --> InnoDB in [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).

Did you recently upgrade MySQL?  If so, any number of problems can occur if the upgrade failed to run `mysql_upgrade`.

What version of MySQL are you running?

Please provide the recent contents of `mysqld.err`.

Please provide `ls -ld /tmp`

Are you using RoundCube?  The bug seems to be related to their installation.

Comment: Maybe your hosting provider updated mysql without notifying you, or you missed the notification somehow.

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible to mysql change some engine tables automatically?

**No**, **`Never`** MySQL any engine change to other MySQL storage engine automatically.
As per siteground blog [here](https://www.siteground.com/kb/how_to_change_the_database_engine_of_a_mysql_database_table/) if your MySQL database is interacting through phpMyAdmin with cPanel. Then the easiest way to change the database engine of a MySQL database table is through phpMyAdmin available in cPanel.

For example, if you have a database table called `my_table` using MyISAM engine and you wish to change the engine from MyISAM to InnoDB you will need to:

Access phpMyAdmin and select your database. Then click the SQL tab, place the following query and click the Go button:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

If the query is executed properly, the database engine of the table will be changed to InnoDB.